# Cloud Haskell & Netwire. Do they overlap? Can both be used effectively?

Tags: haskell, distributed-computing, netwire

Basically, I want to experiment with FRP and distributed Haskell.

I wonder if I could use Netwire for FRP and Cloud Haskell to allow "wires" to be distributed over different "nodes".

But maybe Cloud Haskell already provides FRP. Or maybe Netwire already provides distributed wires.

How could you do distributed FRP?